# On the definition of the second-order derivative of a Morse function

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, morse-theory

In Morse Theory and Floer Homology by Michele Audin and Mihai Damian ([Morse theory and Floer Homology](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4471-5496-9)) they give the following definition to the second-order derivative at a critical point x.
$$(d^2f)_x(X,Y)=X\cdot(\tilde{Y}\cdot f)(x)$$
where $\tilde{Y}$ is a vector field that extends $Y$ and $X,Y$ are vectors tangent to the manifold at $x$.

After giving the statement they give the following example.

Let $(0,0,\varepsilon)\in\mathbb{S^2}$, then $f(x,y)=z=\varepsilon\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$ is a function whose second-order derivative is given by $$(d^2f)_{(0,0,\varepsilon)}(x,y)=-\varepsilon(x^2+y^2)$$

Once I tried to calculate this by using the definition I did not came close to the answer. However, I did manage to find the answer using partial derivatives. But how can I compute the second-order derivative by the given definition.

I assumed $\tilde{Y}\cdot f(x)=\tilde{Y}f(x)=\tilde{Y^i}(x)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}(x)$.

Comment: $f$ having two entries $(x,y)$, how do you compute its differential at a point with three entries $(0,0,\varepsilon)$?

Comment: We look at the neighborhood of $f$ around the point $(0,0,\varepsilon)$ with local coordinates (x,y). Maybe I should place an edit.